# How to dynamically create binding in CollectionViewSource WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In database I have 3 conected tables patient (1)<--(n) study (1)<--(n) card.

I have structure like this:

```
// app.xaml
<Application.Resources>
    <AppName:appnameDataSetApp x:Key="appnameDataSetApp"/>
</Application.Resources>

// main.xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="patientVS"
        Source="{Binding patient, Source={StaticResource appnameDataSetApp}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="studyVS"
        Source="{Binding FK_study_patient, Source={StaticResource patientVS}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cardVS"
        Source="{Binding FK_card_study, Source={StaticResource studyVS}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

It is created when I drag and drop fields from "Data Sources" window in Visual Studio.

Now I want to create new user control (or window) that contain CollectionViewSource connected to `patientVS` from main.
In that CollectionViewSource I will choose specific study, and other components in user control will use this.

I suppose that it must be something like:

```
// study.xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="studyVS_ano" 
        Source="{Binding FK_study_patient, Source={StaticResource
            ?HOW_FROM_PARENT_patientVS?}}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cardVS_ano"
        Source="{Binding FK_card_study, Source={StaticResource studyVS_ano}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxStudy" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource studyVS_ano}}" 
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxCard" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cardVS_ano}}"
```

But I don't know how to create connection to the parent window.

I try this:

```
// study.xaml
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="studyVS_ano"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cardVS_ano"
        Source="{Binding FK_card_study, Source={StaticResource studyVS_ano}}"/>
 </Window.Resources>
...
```

and in initialize method:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    CollectionViewSource patientVS = (CollectionViewSource)parent.FindResource("patientVS");
    CollectionViewSource studyVS_ano = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("studyVS_ano");

    // not working
    studyVS_ano.Source = patientVS;
    // not working
    studyVS_ano.Source = patientVS.View;
    // not working (I know it does not make sense) 
    studyVS_ano.Source = "{Binding FK_study_patient, Source={StaticResource patientVS}}"
}
```

but when I use `Source` form parent studyVS:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    CollectionViewSource studyVS = (CollectionViewSource)parent.FindResource("studyVS");
    CollectionViewSource studyVS_ano = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("studyVS_ano");

    // working !
    studyVS_ano.Source = studyVS.Source;
}
```

This works but not quite, because when I change the current patient in `patientVS` view, `studyVS` changes correctly, but `studyVS_ano` do not change.

I want to create multiple *study.xaml* controls.

**How to create binding or something to connect two CollectionViewSource objects?**

Comment: You would not have to deal with all this if you just had this tables in your ViewModel with an appropriate data access layer. AT the very least have the collection view in your ViewModel.

Comment: From the question is not clear what you want to do. Try to ask better. Do you want to create new collection that will merge items from two collection? Or do you want to use collection in multiple usercontrols?